# MD5 hash for xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: 14.04, md5sum

I cant find the MD5 hash for xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso anywhere [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

PS: I know that the 14.04 MD5 are there.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS). The hash is

```
8b06ac9d76186721312c17a851801e2e *xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [MD5SUMS of xubuntu](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/14.04/release/MD5SUMS)

Answer (score 0):

If your download source has a .metalink file you can read the XML and see the  element.

I just had to do this for xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso which had
`<hash type="md5">8b06ac9d76186721312c17a851801e2e</hash>`
in the `xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.metalink` file.